# Unable to execute command with PHP

Tags: php, nginx

This is my php (`turnOn.php`) :

```
<?php
    system('codesend 6984294');
?>
```

I have nginx, when I access to it via a web browser the system() does not launch (if I add `echo 'something'` in the php file it works though).
However when I shell this : `php turnOn.php` it does work.

I thought it was a user privilege issue so I edited my sudoers file with visudo and added this :

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I know it's unsafe but it does not work either. I don't know where it can come from.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is command `codesend` in your $PATH?  Actually is it in the path of the user running nginx?  Try with the full path to `codesend`.

Comment: It's not in the nginx $PATH, but I replaced : `system('/var/www/html/rf/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend 6984302');`but it does not work either...

Comment: Any logs, errors anywhere?  What does system() return?  Add redirection of output to your command: `system('.../codesend 6984302 >/tmp/out1 2>/tmp/out2');` it might show you something about the execution of codesend in these temp output files.

Comment: Ok I get this : `wiringPiSetup: Unable to open /dev/mem or /dev/gpiomem: Permission denied.
  Try running with sudo?`I think codesend use wiringPi, so I think I should add wiringPi to the sudoers file for www-data ?

Comment: Have you tried `php turnOn.php` in root user or www-data ? because i think the command you want to execute want root access, just check it out.

Comment: I tried to switch to www-data user but I was unable to because it did ask me for a password...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this.

Thanks to Nic3500 I was able to see that codesend needed to access root commands so I just added sudo before my command :

```
system('sudo /var/www/html/rf/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend 6984302');
```

I finally allowed the right directory in the sudoers file :

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/rf/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend
```